# HTML Bootstrap5 grid system with variable heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to understand the bootstrap grid system to archieve this:

[image: layout with bootstrap]

The problem is that in my understanding we structure things in rows (and in these rows we divide them with columns) but in the screenshot there are different row heights in the columns and also a column overflow on the bottom right. How can I archieve something like this?

Thank you in advance!